# Python ctypes. How to pass IN LPVOID to C++ function

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to use ctypes to pass a string to a C++ function, and get one in return.  The function declaration is:

```
BOOL PERFORMAXCOM_API _stdcall SendReceive(IN HANDLE pHandle, 
                          IN LPVOID wBuffer,
                          IN DWORD dwNumBytesToWrite,
                          IN DWORD dwNumBytesToRead,
                          OUT LPVOID rBuffer)
```

I am happy enough with the `HANDLE` and `DWORD` variables, and I achieved an `OUT LPVOID` in a similar function with the following setup:

```
szReplyBuffer = create_string_buffer(64)
ReplyBuffer = c_char_p(addressof(szReplyBuffer))
```

Which when used with a similar `OUT LPVOID` got a string back.

My current method at creating the `IN LPVOID` from an inputted string `cmdStr` (for example "E0=1") is:

```
szSendStr = c_char * 64
SendStr = szSendStr()

for i in range(len(cmdStr)):
    SendStr[i] = cmdStr[i]
```

I then pass this to the function using the following declaration:
    `Status = SendReceive(byref(hUSBDevice), c_void_p(addressof(SendStr)), 64, 64, ReplyBuffer)`

I have tried lots of different permutations of passing the `SendStr` to the function, but never get anything by an empty string back in `ReplyBuffer`.  Is there a way of passing the string which I am missing?

Thanks

Laurence

Comment: I don't think I fully understand your problem, but here in the example there is no problem: the DLL code: http://codepad.org/iI5bfYfh and the python code: http://codepad.org/83aoaQlc .

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I have looked into it further and I see what is actually my problem is that I am able to use the function call in one of my python function definitions, but not another. I will investigate further but could there be a problem as I am passing the HANDLE from function to function?